# Listening on Same Host and Port Twice Does Not Trigger an Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, port

```
const http  = require("http");

function createServer(
  name,
  hostname
)
{
  const server = http.createServer(
    (
      request,
      response
    ) =>
    {
      console.log("request on", name);
      response.end(name);
    }
  );

  server.on(
    "error",
    (error) => console.log(`${name} error`, error)
  );

  server.on(
    "close",
    () => console.log(`${name} closed`)
  );

  server.listen(4321, hostname, () => console.log(`${name} listening (${server.listening}) on address`, server.address()));
}

createServer(
  "Server 1",
  "localhost"
);

createServer(
  "Server 2",
  "127.0.0.1"
);

createServer(
  "Server 3",
  "127.0.1.1"
);

createServer(
  "Server 4",
  "localhost"
);

createServer(
  "Server 5",
  "10.9.129.49"
);

createServer(
  "Server 6",
  "localhost"
);
```

Using Node v6.15.1, v8.14.1, and v10.15.0 the above code prints this on my computer:

```
Server 2 listening (true) on address { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 4321 }
Server 3 listening (true) on address { address: '127.0.1.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 4321 }
Server 5 listening (true) on address { address: '10.9.129.49', family: 'IPv4', port: 4321 }
Server 1 listening (true) on address { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 4321 }
Server 4 listening (true) on address { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 4321 }
Server 6 listening (true) on address { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 4321 }
```

How is this possible? I would have expected an `EADDRINUSE` error to be triggered.

**EDIT** A previous version of this question only showed two servers using the host name `localhost`. The code has been updated to demonstrate that the issue seems to persist regardless of the server count or host.

**UPDATE**

I tried mixing different host names that point to my computer (`localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, my local IP, etc.), and even though the `address` object printed shows different values for `address()` no errors occur.

I am curious if it relates Node.js's [`server.listen`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) method allowing itself to be called multiple times. Maybe Node.js detects that all of the host names I used bind to the same device and port, so it just "re-opens" as the documentation says it would.

Comment: Well, both the servers are running on the same process ID so...

Comment: I am wondering about the sequence of console output. Should console print "server 1 .." before "server 2 .." as server 1 is invoked earlier. I would suggest to check if any server.closed event is fired.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Interesting thought. I ran the script in two separate terminals and still got the same output from both, though. Thanks for the response anyway.

@AndiKleinbichler I added `close` events (as shown in the edited version above) but still received the same output.

Comment: Q: Can you do 3 servers listening on the same host and port?!

I'm wondering if one is just taking up TCP and the other is *magically* taking up UDP and that is why you can do two? However 3 would fail?

Q: I know they've released a whole bunch of things in the newer versions of node... wondering if you might want to try using nvm to switch the version to something like 8+ and retry?

Q: When throwing traffic at that endpoint... do both server's respond? does it crash? Do they round-robin? OMG WHAT HAPPENS! Love this puzzle, thanks for sharing! Interested to find out whats going on!

Comment: @isaacdre I added some new servers to test your TCP/UDP theory. It seems the number of servers does not matter. I also tried on v8.14.1 and v10.15.0, and the results look to be the same. When running all six servers, it seems the first one to bind to the _given_ host name (not the one shown by `address()`) is the one that serves the requests, even if I use the host name shown by `address()` to connect. Lastly, there is an oddity where the request listener seems to be called twice per request regardless of host requested.

Comment: Interesting!
I'm assuming that this is just a edge case that the current node versions don't support catching... Looks like you're doing everything right, but node doesn't even realize there is a conflict.